# JavaFX Real Fullscreen on macOS

Tags: macos, javafx, fullscreen, stage

I want a `javafx.stage.Stage` to be in fullscreen mode on macOS with no (native) menu bar visible. Also I want that the dock is not available while the application is in fullscreen mode.

I have a `Stage` and I set `stage.setFullScreen(true)`. If the style of my stage is set to `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)`, the application displays the native menu bar and the dock. Therefore the whole screen isn't available for the application.

[image]

If I set the style to `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY)` the menu bar is not visible, but instead there is a grey area.

[image]

And if I move the cursor where usually the menu bar is placed, the menu bar will show itself additionally with a small closing button and a small bar.

[image]

Also If I cursor the mouse down where the dock is placed, the dock will show up itself.

How can I achieve a real fullscreen application with no menubar and no dock displayed and no grey bar at the top so my application can use all of the screen size?

## Code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Fullscreen extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        //stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight() + 16);
        //stage.setY(-16);
    }
}
```

## Annotation

If I set `stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight() + 16)` and `stage.setY(-16)` after `stage.show()` and the style is set to `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY)`, the grey bar isn't visible anymore. But this seems not to be a good solution for me because it depends on the screen size (in my case 2560x1440) and I don't know how to exactly get the size of the grey bar. Also the menubar and the dock are available.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Stage#setFullScreen(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-) is the correct way. When I run this [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I get the expected OS X full screen (no dock, automatically hidden menu bar):

```
public class FullScreenDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Label("Foo")));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

I don't think you can get rid of the native menu bar that pops up when you hover over its position—that's just how the OS behaves. The corresponding Javadoc also states:

> The implementation of full-screen mode is platform and profile-dependent.

Comment: Using the StageStyle.Decorated works for me too. My fault  was using the undecorated style cause I thought for my fullscreen application I don't need decorations. But is there really no way to get rid of the menu bar and the dock? If you look at computer games, there are also no menu bars and docks. But there are mostly written in C or C++. Are there no workarounds for java too?

Comment: @Tazmo yep, using the default (`DECORATED`) is fine like the MWE demonstrates. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any solution that removes the native menu bar for a video game-like experience.